# List-style sumindo ao usar 'columns'

Tags: html5, css3

Estou usando 'columns' na ul para dividir meu menu em 2 colunas. Mais ao usar, o list-style some. Por que razão? Existe a possibilidade de não sumir?

```
<ul id="menu-footer">
  <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="empresa.php">empresa</a></li>
  <li><a href="servicos.php">servicos</a></li>
  <li><a href="produtos.php">produtos</a></li>
  <li><a href="contatos.php">contatos</a></li>
</ul>

footer #menu-footer { -webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; -o-column-count: 2; -ms-column-count: 2; column-count: 2; list-style-position: inside;}
footer #menu-footer li {list-style: square; color: #fff;}
```

Comment: Editei a resposta baseado em seus códigos.

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa adicionar **[list-style-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp)**, para especificar que os marcadores devem aparecer dentro do fluxo do conteúdo:

```
.menu{
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
   list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Exemplo: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLBFR/)**

### Editado

Você tem alguns problemas com seus seletores CSS, altere em seu código de `footer #menu-footer` para `footer > #menu-footer` e `footer #menu-footer li` para `footer > #menu-footer.li`. Para maior entendimento **[seletores](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)**

```
footer > #menu-footer { 
    -webkit-column-count: 2; 
    -moz-column-count: 2; 
    -o-column-count: 2; 
    -ms-column-count: 2; 
    column-count: 2; 
    list-style-position: inside;
}
footer > #menu-footer.li {
list-style: square; color: #fff;
}
```

**Exemplo2: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLBFR/3/)**

Comment: Tentei reproduzir no meu código e não funcionou :(

Comment: Poste seu código para verificarmos

Comment: Ainda não funcionou. Deve ter alguma outra coisa interferindo.

Comment: @Lucas Então você deve ter alguma outra propriedade conflitando em seu CSS, tente colocar `list-style-position: inside !important;`.